# How to use same local package in two projects?

Tags: meteor

I have two projects: `xxx-api` and `xxx-web`, and both will use same local package `xxx::libs`

How to maintain `xxx::libs` ? currently I put xxx::lib under `xxx-api`, and whenever I update it, I will copy whole directory to `xxx-web/packages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a directory somewhere - let's call it `/home/user/pacakges`.
2. Place your package (let's call it `my-package`) in that directory.
3. `export PACKAGE_DIRS="/home/user/packages"`
4. `cd` into your each app directory and `meteor add my-pacakge` (if you haven't already)

That's it! Meteor will always search your `PACKAGE_DIRS` **before** checking for any packages within your app. Make sure to add the export to your environment.

Fore more details I'd recommend reading my blog post on [local pacakges](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages).

Answer (score 0):

[mgp](https://github.com/DispatchMe/mgp) may help you share private meteor packages in an easy way.
Maintain your `xxx::libs` in a separated directory.
And use `mgp link` to `xxx::libs` in your projects `xxx-api` and `xxx-web`.