# is it possible to have multiple projects with shared code?

Tags: meteor

I would like to create a Meteor project which will be over the web for PC and mobile platforms.
The HTML files will be different for each project however the JavaScript logic should be the same.

Is it possible to create 2 Meteor projects (one for web and other for mobile) with shared JS files?
Maybe using another project?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing and reusing code is the very first reason for the existence of [Meteor packages](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/packagejs).

To create one simply `meteor create --package me:mypackage` (assuming `me` is your Meteor developer account username).

You can add your logic in the package. You can do anything you would normally do in your application development (templates, publications/subscriptions, collections, CSS, ...).
You can then simply publish this package to Atmosphere and reuse it in other projects.

```
meteor publish --create me:mypackage
```

There is a lot to know about packages. See more [about publishing](https://atmospherejs.com/i/publishing), [testing packages with Jasmine](https://velocity.readme.io/docs/jasmine-testing-a-meteor-package).

Comment: Or create a local package, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061910/how-to-use-same-local-package-in-two-projects).